# Deploy EAR with Jenkins on Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build and deploy my application.

The build step is succesfully done. But the deploy step is not done. I've tried two things.

- **1st try :**

I set the ant target value to **run-deploy**, I got this Exception

```
    /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VecturaTest/nbproject/ant-deploy.xml:89: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:728)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.get(Get.java:641)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.run(Get.java:631)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 13 more
```

- **2nd try :**

I use [Deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin), no eception is show in the log but my application is not deployed. I set these parameters :

```
- Fichiers WAR/EAR : /absolute/path/myapp.ear
- Context path : I don't know what to do here, I tried /myapp
- GlassFish home : /opt/glasfish3/glassfish
- GlassFish hostname : the IP adress of the server
```

Why doesn't these 2 tries work? Wrong parameters? Other plugin dependency? ... ?

Thank you in advance for your help!

NB : I don't use MAEVEN

Comment: Not sure about Glassfish, but most servers have a deploy directory where you can put the packaged app and it will be discovered and deployed. Why not just use comandline copy to move created ear to such folder?

Comment: "/opt/glasfish3/glassfish" - is that a typo?

Comment: @Nadir - What is the latest plugin to execute postbuil command?

Comment: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task

Comment: problem of permission with Post Build command!